# Mysql: get records that have no subsequent records with certain attributes

Tags: mysql, join

I'm sorry if topic title is not so clear; I try to explain better (or help me to write a better title)

I have a message table which typically contains questions and answers.
I would need to select records with certain characteristics that have been read but have not been answered

```
CREATE TABLE `sf_messages` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `messagedate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `messagefrom` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `messageto` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `messagetext` text NOT NULL,
 `ack` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `checkid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `messagefrom` (`messagefrom`),
 KEY `messageto` (`messageto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `sf_messages` 
(`messagedate`, `messagefrom`, `messageto`, `messagetext`, `ack`, 
`checkid`)
VALUES 
('2021-06-24 08:00:00',122,237,'This is checkid 100',1,100),
('2021-06-24 08:02:00',122,237,'Ok?',1,0),
('2021-06-24 09:00:00',237,122,'Yes, ok!',1,0),
('2021-06-24 10:00:00',122,767,'This is checkid 101',1,101),
('2021-06-24 10:02:00',122,767,'Ok?',1,0),
('2021-06-24 11:00:00',767,122,'Yes, ok!',1,0),
('2021-06-24 12:00:00',122,999,'This is checkid 102',1,102),
('2021-06-24 12:02:00',122,999,'Ok?',1,0),
('2021-06-25 09:02:00',122,999,'Hey man?',1,0)

SELECT * FROM sf_messages
WHERE checkid and ack
```

(I have to get only the checkid 102 record)

Here's the db-fiddle
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ktSXMSC4VPkc2Qnf7gXq5a/4

Thanks in advance
Gian

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your schema and data here - the link to the db-fiddle is prone to get stale leaving this question without any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM sf_messages t1
WHERE checkid 
  AND ack
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM sf_messages t2
                   WHERE t1.messagedate < t2.messagedate
                     AND (t1.messagefrom, t1.messageto) = (t2.messageto, t2.messagefrom));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d749d11a748c1cbcfa81361e1ffea1d9